# Looking for \bigCap or \bigdoublecap

Tags: stacking-symbols

I know `\Cap` (or `\doublecap`) and I know `\bigcap`. However, now I also need `\bigCap` (or `\bigdoublecap`) which is a `\bigcap` with another `\cap` in between.

I already tried using `\stackinset` from the stackengine package, but was not able to produce decent results.

Comment: Do you just [want these symbols overlaid](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RSWt4.png)?

Comment: I could live with that solution, although a smaller `\cap` would make it better to read.

Comment: i believe this was added to unicode.  check the stix fonts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not pretty, but if nothing else comes along, maybe you can do with this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\newcommand{\bigdoublecap}{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\bigcap}\vcenter{\hbox{\text{%
    \ooalign{$\displaystyle\bigcap$\cr
             \hidewidth
             \raisebox{-.1ex}{\resizebox{.7\width}{.875\height}{$\displaystyle\bigcap$}}%
             \hidewidth\cr
    }%
  }}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\bigdoublecap_{i=1}^n A_i
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks very pretty to me :)

Comment: @C-Otto Note that a `%` was missing and I added it.

Comment: Noted, thanks. And say hi to Fausto Spoto from me :)

Answer (score 6):

I used `\stackinset` AND routines from the `scalerel` package.  What it insets is a `\bigcap` that has been scaled down to 1.6ex in height (which narrows it to the proper width), and then vertically stretched to 2ex in height.  The manipulated inset is placed, horizontally centered, .15pt above the base of the unaltered `\bigcap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-10-15]
\newcommand\bigdoublecap{%
  \mathop{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{}{b}{.15pt}%
    {\stretchto{\scaleto{\bigcap}{1.6ex}}{2ex}}{\bigcap}}}
}
\begin{document} 
\[
\bigdoublecap_{i=1}^n A_i
\]\end{document}
```

[image]